# Python and beautifulsoup - Scrape Text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/240370/Abengoa-Bioenergy-Company-Llc/244317/Abengoa-Bioenergy-Us-401K-Savings-Plan/'
thepage = requests.get(url)
urlsoup = BeautifulSoup(thepage.text, "html.parser")

plandata = urlsoup.find(class_="plans-section").text

print(plandata)
```

I;m trying to scrape only the class of rating number but when I use this code, I get nothing back :(.

1. How do I scrape only the class of rating number?
2. How could I scrape multiple classes (this is the most important part) and put them into a list thats readable?

My thought would be to loop each page scraped and append them to a .csv file with a new line.

Example below;

```
Rating #1, Company Name1, etc, etc, etc

Rating #2, Company Name2, etc, etc, etc
```

I just can't get over the hump of figuring this out. Thank for any help!

Edit - The class "plans-section" holds the data that I want but it seems to be broken down to two div tags under it. I want to scrape the data in the class "data-text above-average". The problem is that each page seems to only have the same "data-text" and what comes after changes on each section/page. What options are there for me?

Comment: the url you gave does not contain any class='data-text above-average'

Comment: You're right. I just updated the url and it has the class'data-text above-average' but I really want to scrape any class that has "data-text *", I added the asterisk to substitute any text behind "data-text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/141759/Aj-Kirkwood-Associates-Inc/143902/Aj-Kirkwood-Associates-Inc-401K-Profit-Sharing-Plan/'
thepage = requests.get(url)
urlsoup = BeautifulSoup(thepage.text, "html.parser")

rate = urlsoup.find(class_='rating-number').text
name = urlsoup.find(class_="name").text
print(rate, name)
```

out:

```
59 A.J. Kirkwood & Associates, Inc.
```

use `re` filter to match all the class contain certain text:

```
If you pass in a regular expression object, Beautiful Soup will filter against that regular expression using its search() method.
```

in you case:

```
import re
soup.find_all(class_=re.compile(r'data-text.+'))
```

Comment: 'import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/141759/Aj-Kirkwood-Associates-Inc/143902/Aj-Kirkwood-Associates-Inc-401K-Profit-Sharing-Plan/'
thepage = requests.get(url)
urlsoup = BeautifulSoup(thepage.text, "html.parser")

plandata = urlsoup.find(class_="plans-section").text

print(plandata)'

Comment: I'm trying to scrape data from this site that is going to change between each page. The above `code` was supposed to show that. The data I want is under "design

Comment: please update the question, and i will update my answer.

Comment: Just updated it. Hopefully that explains what I'm looking to scrape.

Comment: I keep getting a blank list `[]` am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

What are you exactly wanting to get out of the page? If you are looking to get div by class, this should help.

```
urlsoup.findAll("div", { "class" :"rating-number"})
```